# How to click on an element inside span tag? - Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, qwebelement

Hi I am trying to click on a specific button with text "€11" on it in selenium webdriver in Java.

The button is located within this format and there is also another button on the page with exactly the same code but different price:

```
<button type="button" class="bui-button bui-spacer--medium bui-button--primary bui-button--wide">
<span class="bui-button__text">€11</span>
</button>
```

How would I do this. Any help is appreciated :)

[Full CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YraDC.png)

Comment: actually, the span is your button. it's easiest (if I remember well) to add an id to the span and click using that

Comment: Use `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='button']>span[class='bui-button__text']")).click();` and let me know

Comment: you can also use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='bui-button__text']")).click();

Comment: As _...there is also another button on the page with exactly the same code but different price..._ you need to update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML  so we can differentiate the two buttons.

Comment: added image @DebanjanB

Comment: @Fenomenoq Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

A few options you could use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'€11')]")).click();
```

**Click first button using this:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='bui-button__text'])[1]")).click();
```

**Click second button using this:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='bui-button__text'])[2]")).click();
```

Note: use wait's if you have any delays in loading amount

Answer (score 0):

I know some ways that could help

javascript:

```
document.querySelector("span.bui-button__text").click()
```

jquery:

```
$("body > button > span").click()
```

Selenium (Java):

```
driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("button[class='bui-button bui-spacer--medium bui-button--primary bui-button--wide']").click()
```

I hope that they help you !